# Nextflow installation cannot find Java

Tags: java, nextflow

I'm currently trying to install nextflow on my computer but I'm struggling with a Java error message I can't manage to solve.

```
curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash

ERROR: Cannot find Java or it's a wrong version -- please make sure that Java 8 or later is installed
NOTE: Nextflow is trying to use the Java VM defined by the following environment variables:
 JAVA_CMD: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
 JAVA_HOME:
```

Looking for solution on other posts, I tried to use

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7+)"
```

but now I still have almost same error

```
ERROR: Cannot find Java or it's a wrong version -- please make sure that Java 8 or later is installed
NOTE: Nextflow is trying to use the Java VM defined by the following environment variables:
 JAVA_CMD: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
 JAVA_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

My java version :

```
 java -version
 java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I would be grateful if you could give me some tips to overcome this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the script you're running:

```
...
if [ $major -eq 0 ] && [ $minor -lt 26 ]; then
    version_check="^(1.7|1.8)"
    version_message="Java 7 or 8"
  else
    version_check="^(1.8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15)"
    version_message="Java 8 or later"
  fi
...
```

Looks like it needs Java 15 or earlier. You can probably just add 16 and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to install nextflow utilizing the homebrew or the curl command so I installed it with the instructions that are particular to the bioconda installation portion, when using the nextflow command i didn't get the same java version error.
https://nf-co.re/usage/installation